# JSoup Parsing issues

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am working on Android application that parses a website but I can't seem to get Jsoup to work.

I am trying to parse this html:

[Here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKCtp.png)

My code just now is:

```
Document doc = null;
      try{
     doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
      Elements tds = doc.select("table.tr>td");

     for (Element td : tds) {
       String tdText = td.text();
       System.out.println(tdText);
     }
    }
```

At the moment it does not return anything but if I print 'doc' it return the whole website.

I am trying to extract the following information:
Drower, E. S. (Ethel Stefana), Lady, b. 1879, With or without the &nbsp.

But I can't seam to get it to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't `.` for classes? Children are `foo > bar > baz`.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could mix them. What should it be instead of the mixed example. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: You could mix them, of course, but your selector is still wrong. You are selecting `td` children of a `table` element with class `tr`. Instead you probably want `td` cells in `tr` rows in a `table`. I believe you could get at them just by using `"td"` as selector. However, it would be hard to extract just the information you want, since the `td` containing it has no `id` or any other unique characteristic that may isolate it from the other `td` elements in the page - maybe it's always the third cell of the second row in that specific table?

Comment: Yes that is right, it is always the third cell of the second row in the table. It would also be handy if there was a way to extract the full title and author after the </script> tag, since all of the information is held there as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the selector wrong: it picks `td` children of a `table` element with class `tr`, while you probably want `td` cells in `tr` rows in a `table`. I believe you could get at them just by using `"td"` as selector.

However, that's a bit too generic, since it's going to pick every cell in the table. If the cell you need is always the third cell in the rows of that table, you can refine the selector to pick only those: `"td:eq(2)"`. You should really get a knack of [JSoup selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), and experiment a little bit to see how much you are able to restrict the data extracted from the document to just the elements you really need.

To obtain the text after the `<script>` element in the fourth cell you could use something along the following snippet:

```
Element td = doc.select("td:eq(3)").first();
System.out.println(td.text());
```

because, from a little experiment of mine, it seems that JavaScript code inside `<script>` tags is skipped when asking the text of an element that contains one of those.

You would use a `for` loop rather than `first`, though, since there are as many fourth cells as there are rows in your document, and you got a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help I managed to extract the information I need through this bit of code:
                 String td = doc.select("tr:has(td)").text();
   System.out.println(td);

Comment: @tbone24 you are welcome. If the answer has been helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it.